# PHP HTML form arrays - how to tell when a user adds a new entry

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I apologise for the vagueness of the title but I'm finding this hard to put into words.

I have a form which contains `key:value` pairs which are read from the database, placed as values in inputs and then read back in again (possibly edited, deleted or added to). On the server side, I need to figure out just what the user has done to muck up my data.

Example:

```
<input type='text' name='keyID[]' value='1'/>
<input type='text' name='key[]' value='someKey'/>
<input type='text' name='value[]' value='someValue'/>

<input type='text' name='keyID[]' value='2'/>
<input type='text' name='key[]' value='someOtherKey'/>
<input type='text' name='value[]' value='someOtherValue'/>

<input type='text' name='keyID[]' value='3'/>
<input type='text' name='key[]' value='yetAnotherKey'/>
<input type='text' name='value[]' value='yetAnotherValue'/>

<input type='text' name='key[]' value='aCompletelyNewKey'/>
<input type='text' name='value[]' value='aCompletelyNewValue'/>
```

When the form is submitted, I delete the original data, do a foreach loop through the keys (geting the nth value of the other arrays as my new data), and add this to the database.

This worked up until I hit a snag with my updated database design - now I need to be able to tell what hasn't been submitted (removed on the page), what's still there (been changed or left as-is), and what is new (won't have a `keyID[]`).

I've been using `array_diff()` against a list of currently stored `keyID[]`s to figure out what to delete and update, but how would I figure out what has been added when there won't be a `keyID[]` for the new inputs (but there will be both a `key[]` and `value[]`)?

Also I can't guarantee the order in which the values of the arrays will be submitted so I don't think counting to the end of the `keyID[]` array and then checking the others for extra values would give me the correct values every time.

Any ideas?

Comment: For the new inputs, you should include `keyID[]` anyway, and just give it a blank value `value=''`. This way when you loop through you can just check for that value. If it's empty, then you know it's a new k/v pair being added.

Comment: common sense wins again :) thanks guys, it's true i've overcomplexified the problem, the simple solution is the best :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea is to change slightly the last block, like this:

```
...
<input type='hidden' name='keyID[]' value='NEW'/>
<input type='text' name='key[]' value='aCompletelyNewKey'/>
<input type='text' name='value[]' value='aCompletelyNewValue'/>
```

This way, all three arrays will have the same number of elements. In addition, it is now trivial to see whether something is new or not.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense to do, no matter what method you end up employing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be overcomplicating it a little bit. You can pass an ID in the name of your field, so you can identify it directly. Usually this would be the record ID from the database, or some other unique identifier. Lets assume the checkboxes turn on/off a 'featured' flag - so what you could do is something similar to this:

```
<input name="featured[<?php echo $record['id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $record['value']; ?>">
```

The $record['value'] is always going to hold some data (it might just be a blank string) which will update/process on submitting.

When you submit, you'll need to iterate through your $_POST['featured'] array as $key=>$value and set the value of the record to $value where the record id is equal to $key. If the record doesn't exist to update, you could create a new one using the INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE sql command.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you place the keyID inside each record [], you can check back at your database which one was updated, and how.

For example:

```
<input type='text' name='key[1]' value='someKey'/>
<input type='text' name='value[1]' value='someValue'/>

<input type='text' name='key[2]' value='someOtherKey'/>
<input type='text' name='value[2]' value='someOtherValue'/>

<input type='text' name='key[3]' value='yetAnotherKey'/>
<input type='text' name='value[3]' value='yetAnotherValue'/>

<input type='text' name='key[n]' value='aCompletelyNewKey'/>
<input type='text' name='value[n]' value='aCompletelyNewValue'/>
```

Note that `[n]`, if generated through javascript, would need to be automatically incremented.

Another suggestion would be to invert the keyID and the `key|value` names, so that you could receive and compare each array element with the database. But that would need a prefix (like the tablename):

```
<input type='text' name='tablename[1][key]' value='someKey'/>
<input type='text' name='tablename[1][value]' value='someValue'/>
```